# iterating through a list consisting of nested tuples/dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

I have the following list which has nested tuples/dicts.

```
list1 = [ 
            ('key1', {'count': 10, 'value1': Counter({'set1': 5, 'set2': 4, 'set3': 1})}), 
            ('key2', {'count': 8, 'value1': Counter({'set1': 6, 'set2': 2})}),
            ('key3', {'count': 7, 'value1': Counter({'set1': 5, 'set2': 2, 'set3': 1})}) 
        ]
```

This is what I have so far;

```
for key, value in list1:
    print key, value['count'], '|||', value['value1'].keys(), value['value1'].values()

Result:
key1  10 ||| ['set1', 'set2', 'set3'] [5, 4, 1]
key2  8  ||| ['set1', 'set2'] [6, 2]
key3  7  ||| ['set1', 'set2', 'set3'] [5, 2, 1]
```

What I can't figure out is how to make it iterate through each set and print its count like this;

```
key1  10 ||| set1 5, set 4, set3 1
key2  8  ||| set1 6, set2 2
key3  7  ||| set1 5, set2 2, set3 1
```

For the Counter value, I can seem to get only the keys or only the values, but not iterate through them one at a time as shown above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Counter` objects are just dictionaries with extra behaviour, so you can also use `dict.items()`. However, I'd use a different method here unique to `Counter` objects.

Loop over the [`Counter.most_common()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) and format the tuples this yields into a string:

```
for key, value in list1:
    print key, value['count'], '|||', ', '.join(['%s %d' % kv for kv in value['value1'].most_common()])
```

You may want to use string formatting with `str.format()` to create the column formatting:

```
for key, value in list1:
    print '{}  {:<2d} ||| {}'.format(
        key, value['count'],
        ', '.join(['%s %d' % kv for kv in value['value1'].most_common()]))
```

`Counter.most_common()` produces key-value pairs in order of highest count to lowest.

Demo of the latter:

```
>>> for key, value in list1:
...     print '{}  {:<2d} ||| {}'.format(
...         key, value['count'],
...         ', '.join(['%s %d' % kv for kv in value['value1'].most_common()]))
...
key1  10 ||| set1 5, set2 4, set3 1
key2  8  ||| set1 6, set2 2
key3  7  ||| set1 5, set2 2, set3 1
```

Comment: Thank you very much, exactly what I was looking for. I didn't realize Counter most_common() function could be used there, very useful.

Comment: Hey, by any chance to save me creating a new question, do you know how I might be able to format this with .format? I've tried `'{1} {0}'.format(*(kv for kv in value['value1'].most_common()))`. It doesn't work, but when I do a `for kv in value['value1'].most_common():
 print "{1} {0}".format(*kv)` it does. Reason is I want to change the order of the %s and %d.

Comment: @user1165419: you only have two slots in your string format, but are trying to pass in a *list of pairs*. That won't work. You need to format individual pairs, then join the result with commas in between: `', '.join(['{1:d} {0}'.format(*kv) for kv in value['value1'].most_common()])`